# How to create image of SKSpriteNode?

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, 2d-games

I have a **SKSpriteNode** with a lot of child nodes. 
I use that node with all the children very frequently in my game.

A better approach would be to build this node once with all the children, create an image (**SKTexture**) and use the created texture, as opposed to recreating the SKSpriteNode and all its children.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Could you please give more details about how you initialize this SKSpriteNode, what it looks like (do you have a custom class for it?) and where/when do you need to use it (many times in one single Scene, or many times in many different Scenes) ?

Comment: Are you sure that having this node and it’s children is causing performance issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a very easy way to do this.. I do this all the time to convert ShapeNodes to SpriteNodes (because shapes need 1 draw call per shape, and sprites dont)

`let texture = SKView().texture(from: desiredNode)`
`let newSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)`

or, in your gamescene for brevity:
`let newSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: view!.texture(from: desiredNode))`

Comment: Oh, Thanks!! It's very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

### SKEffectNode & shouldRasterize

You can us `SKEffectNode` and set `shouldRasterize` to `true`.

```
let effectNode = SKEffectNode()
effectNode.shouldRasterize = true
scene.addChild(effectNode)
```

> The SKEffectNode's output is rasterized and cached internally. This cache is reused when rendering.

Now just add your sprites to `effectNode`

```
effectNode.addChild(sprite0)
effectNode.addChild(sprite1)
effectNode.addChild(sprite2)
```

The first time the `effectNode` is rendered, the produced image will be automatically cached.
And the cached version will be used for the next frames.